# Xamarin.Forms - Force ListView layout to redraw

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, redraw

I have a ListView with `HasUnevenRows = true`, where the content of each cell is variant to begin with, but the content can also change on the fly (through clicking of a button in the cell). When the ListView initially loads, ***the system must perform a calculation*** in order to correctly determine and draw the heights of each cell based on their content.

**But** when I update the content after the initial load, this same calculation is apparently not done, because the height of the cell does not change -- until I've scrolled that item out of view and then back into view.

***How can I force this same calculation and redraw manually, without completely refreshing the ListView??***

I tried wrapping the ListView in a Frame and calling `.ForceLayout()` on the frame, but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The height of the cells aren't recalculated by default because it is an expensive process.  If you want to force a re-size you need to call **ForceUpdateSize()** on the cell.

NOTE: This does not work on older versions of Xamarin Forms.  It was added in 2.0.0.0, but try updating to at least 2.2.0.31

Comment: Interesting - I just tried that, but my application crashed on calling that command. I created a button inside the cell with a `.Clicked` event calling `ForceUpdateSize()`.

Comment: `ForceUpdateSize()`, haha - just that.

Comment: So.....turns out my Xamarin.Forms version was the problem. I was on 2.1.0.6526. Once I upgraded to 2.2.0.31, it worked!!

Answer (score 5):

Set your CachingStrategy="RetainElement", it's expensive, but will force an update  a lot more. If your list isn't too long, you won't notice.

I've noticed that if a cell is visible, even though bound to an obserablecollection, that cell doesn't update until I scroll up then down.

Comment: I used CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" and it worked.

Comment: Using Maui, Listview with nested groups/elements.
I also had/have the same initial refresh issue: when an item was displayed I show blank, although the expected size.
Setting CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" on the ListView resolved, the item is displayed when it is first shown. It feels slower, will ahve to check that.

Answer (score 3):

I've had terrible luck getting native controls to redraw. The one thing that has worked for me has been in a custom renderer: `((IVisualElementController)Element).NativeSizeChanged()`

Comment: I tried various combinations of SizeToFit, SetNeedsDisplay and SetNeedsLayout. None worked. NativeSizeChanged did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DataBinding if you want your view to refresh automatically..

Comment: I don't want to refresh the data, I only want to redraw the list in its current state.

Comment: Do you use a DataTemplate for your listview?

Comment: Yes, I have a separate file for the DataTemplate.

Comment: I know that when you delete something from your list and your itemsource is observableCollection it works, it upgrades the view.. but i don't know if it will work for you. And i also dont know if you can have different sizes per row in a listview.

Comment: I think in your datatemplate you should have something like
 if(condition==true) layout.Add(newLabel)
else layout.remove(newLabel)
to get condition value of your object you have to use databinding

Comment: @MrKocak - what does that have to do with dynamically changing the height? Sorry, I'm not following.

Answer (score 0):

```
        YourListView.BeginRefresh ();
        YourListView.EndRefresh ();
```

But i strongly recommend not to do this.

Comment: I don't want to completely refresh the list, because I'm in a particular state of an item that I need to preserve.

Comment: It will not refresh it. It will just recalculate row/list heights

Comment: I just tried it, but it has no effect. I added a "refresh" button with a `.Clicked` event that calls `myListView.BeginRefresh()` and `myListView.EndRefresh();` No luck. In the clicked even, I even called a `myListView.TranslateX = 100;` to make sure it was affecting the list correctly, and it was - that worked. But BeginRefresh and EndRefresh didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and effective way is:

```
myListView.ItemsSource = null;
MyListView.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection;
```